# How can I link images that are in a slideshow to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slideshow written in JavaScript as such:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var image1 = new Image()
            image1.src = "http://www.goodgamebro.com/omega/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/nhl-15-crosby.jpg"
        var image2 = new Image()
            image2.src = "http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/002/510/570/NHL14_original_crop_north.jpg?w=495&h=330&q=75"

        var image3 = new Image()
            image3.src = "http://media1.gameinformer.com/filestorage/CommunityServer.Components.SiteFiles/imagefeed/featured/electronic-arts2014/easports/nhl15/nhl0709-610.jpg"

        var image4 = new Image()
            image4.src = "http://8bitchimp.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/6f20d61086a798f4b559d1e0043731b36f75cced98896fad16b282abbcbd3bac_large.jpg"

        var image5 = new Image()
            image5.src = "http://cdn3.vox-cdn.com/imported_assets/2324396/nhl-15-scottrade-center.jpg"

        var image6 = new Image()
            image6.src = "http://www.pastapadre.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/nhl15gctrailer.jpg"
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<6)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()", 10000);
        }
        slideit();
    </script>
</body>
```

Is there a way to link these images that are in the slideshow to another page on my website?

Comment: *"is there a way to link these images that are in the slideshow to another page on my website"* - The same way you linked them to your slideshow, use the original source URL.

Comment: Instead of using `evil`.. excuse me `eval` you could do `window['image'+step].src`, elimating the use of `eval`.

Comment: @Mouser Aren't globals also `evil`?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes, lesser evil than `eval` If global is *Sauron* then eval is *Melkor/Morgoth*.

Comment: have yo tried html concatenation inside js?