# How can I link an image to another page on my website?

Tags: html

I have an image coded as such:

```
<img src="http://cdn.fansided.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/229/files/2014/06/nhl15cover610.jpg" width="500" height="300"/>
```

Using html, how can I link this image to another page on my website?

Comment: Um, wrap it in an anchor element with an href attribute? Seems like HTML 101.

Comment: @j08691 Is this the same if the images are in a slideshow?

Comment: Who knows? You never mentioned a slideshow until you posted your comment. Plus, you posted no code for a slideshow, so I can't say.

Comment: @j08691 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284046/how-can-i-link-images-that-are-in-a-slideshow-to-another-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<a href="somepageonyoursite.html"><img src="http://cdn.fansided.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/229/files/2014/06/nhl15cover610.jpg" width="500" height="300"/></a>
```

You use the anchor tag  to create links to other areas of both your site or the internet itself.